# can I increase memory to my flows on prefect cloud?

Tags: prefect

I know I can increase memory allocation for my flows using code. But can I do the same thing on Prefect Cloud somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, you can - it depends on what you are asking. What is currently a bottleneck for you?

E.g. you can allocate more memory to your VM, Kubernetes job or a serverless container used as infrastructure blocks. Here is an example for `KubernetesJob`:

```py
from prefect.infrastructure import KubernetesJob

k8s_job = KubernetesJob(
    namespace="prefect",
    customizations=[
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/spec/template/spec/resources",
            "value": {"limits": {"memory": "8Gi", "cpu": "4000m"}},
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/spec/template/spec/resources",
            "value": {"requests": {"memory": "2Gi", "cpu": "1000m"}},
        }
    ],
)
k8s_job.save("prod")
```

and here is one for `ECSTask`:

```py
from prefect_aws.ecs import ECSTask
from prefect_aws.credentials import AwsCredentials


aws_credentials_block = AwsCredentials(
    aws_access_key_id="xxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="yyy",
)
ecs = ECSTask(
    aws_credentials=aws_credentials_block,
    cpu="256",
    memory="512",
)
ecs.save("prod")
```